# I need help creating a collision system in a java platforming game

Tags: java, processing, collision

I'm creating a simple platforming game using processing and need help figuring out a way to let my player character interact with platforms, specifically letting them stand on top of the platforms.

I've tried to set the player's velocity to zero when they interact with the platform, but it creates a problem when trying  to go on top of the platform, where the player would sink through instead of staying on top.

```
    public void setup() {
        background=loadImage("Sprites/Test Background-1.png.png");
        playerSprite= new AnimatedSprite("Idle animation", 8);
        blocks[0]= new BlockCollision();
        blocks[0].Sprite = loadImage("Sprites/Platform Small-1.png.png" );
        blocks[0].x = 250;
        blocks[0].y = 250;
        blocks[0].width = 64;
        blocks[0].height= 64;
        blocks[1]= new BlockCollision();
        blocks[1].Sprite = loadImage("Sprites/Platform Small-1.png.png" );
        blocks[1].x = 0;
        blocks[1].y = 0;
        blocks[1].width = 64;
        blocks[1].height = 64;
        blocks[2]= new BlockCollision();
        blocks[2].Sprite = loadImage("Sprites/Platform Small-1.png.png");
        blocks[2].x = 300;
        blocks[2].y = 400;
        blocks[2].width = 64;
        blocks[2].height = 64;

    }
    public void settings() {
        size (500, 500);
    }
    public void draw() {
        background(background);
        if(grounded==false){
            playerVelocity.y += 1;
        }
        playerPosition.x +=
                playerVelocity.x;
        playerPosition.y +=
                playerVelocity.y;
        if (playerPosition.y > 468) {
            playerPosition.y = 468;
            playerVelocity.y = 0;
            jumpAmount=0;
        }
        playerSprite.animate
                (playerPosition.x, playerPosition.y);
            //checks for if it touches any side of the platform
        if(playerPosition.y+ playerDimensions>= blocks[0].y
                && playerPosition.x+ blockDimensions>=blocks[0].x
                &&playerPosition.y<=blocks[0].y+blockDimensions
                && playerPosition.x<=blocks[0].x){
//sets velocity to zero to ensure that any other interaction with the platform works
            playerVelocity.x=0;
            playerVelocity.y=0;

            if(playerPosition.y+ blockDimensions<=blocks[0].y){
                grounded=true;
            }
            else grounded = false;
        }


        image(blocks[0].Sprite, blocks[0].x, blocks[0].y);
        image(blocks[1].Sprite,blocks[1].x,blocks[1].y);
        image(blocks[2].Sprite,blocks[2].x,blocks[2].y);
    }
```

The player is meant to still be grounded on the platform, but the player sinks through instead.

Comment: Could you add some comments to make your logic a bit clearer?  Where's the (0,0) for each object and is positive y up or down?

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be with an obstacle Matrix, filled with 0 for allow (move) and 1 with disallow move (and stay there if reach)
Matrix size can reflect screen size eg.(800x600).For an much more ease of use you could assume that 1 square = 4x4 pixels and reduce matrix size from (800x600) to (200x150).

Other solution can be done with checking some rectangular portion of other object in conjunction with object type (ground, enemy, obstacle). Basically all objects could be wrapped inside various rectangular shape (or more complex if need accurate collisions).

Comment: What would be the best/most effective way to do your second proposed idea?

Comment: Eg: The hero (character) will be within a square (100X80) pixels. Static object :up_wall will be within (300,50) px. Need a list of object with their type (hero, wall, etc) . With static is pretty simple, since coords on screen will not change . On position on screen need one (x,y) for screen (top,left)(100,100) and the and the object (with size 300,50) . So screen area C (from 100->300+100, 100->100+50y ... related to screen) will be the collision area within hero. For each change in x or/and y for hero, always check the collision area.On top of collision (object), down should not be allowed.

Comment: form the obj_list (wall, other objects) always check for each hero coords (x or/and y) modification the collision. Eg. x hero 80 , goes to 81. Obj1 is at 81_x so not allowed. Hope to be usefull for you the idea. For start just try with a static obj, then goes with dynamic (coord will be changing for dynamic but you will have in the obj_list)